# Swagger openapi 3.0.x empty body

Tags: express, swagger, openapi, swagger-jsdocs

I am trying to migrate my from swagger 2.0 to openapi 3.0.2 for my express api.
The swagger definitions and paths are written in swagger-jsdoc. This should cause no problems because their documentation state that it can work with openapi 3.x as well as with swagger 2.0.

When adding openapi: 3.0.x to my swaggerDefinition the views look fine.
However when trying to do a post request through the swagger views, the body is empty.

My swagger definition looks like this:

```
const swaggerOptions = {
    swaggerDefinition: {
        openapi: '3.0.2',
        info: {
            title: `Channels API`,
            description: "Channels API",
            version: "v1"
        },
        servers: [ {
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
            description: 'Local server'
        }],
    },
    apis: ['./routes/*.js'],
};
```

Now I have a file channels.js as a router:
It has the following definition in it:

```
class Channel extends BaseRouter {
/**
* @swagger
*
* definitions:
*   channel:
*     type: object
*     tags:
*       - Channels
*     properties:
*       name:
*           type: string
*       global:
*           type: boolean
*     required:
*       - name
*/

constructor(app, version) {
    super(app, new ChannelCtrl(), version);
}

post() {
    /**
     * @swagger
     * /api/v1/channels:
     *  post:
     *      tags:
     *          - Channels
     *      name: Create
     *      produces:
     *          - application/json
     *      consumes:
     *          - application/json
     *      summary: Create new channel object
     *      parameters:
     *       - name: channel
     *         required: true
     *         in: body
     *         description: Fields of the channel object to be created
     *         type: object
     *         schema:
     *             $ref: '#/definitions/channel'
     *      responses:
     *          '200':
     *              description: Channel object has been created
     *              application/json:
     *                  schema:
     *                      $ref: '#/definitions/channel'
     */
    this.app.post(`/api/${this.version}/channels`, this.controller.create.bind(this.controller));
    return this;
}
```

Trying it with swagger 2.0 seems to work fine..
What am I missing?

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution to this ? @ARR

Comment: @OrkunOzen, nope for now I switched back to swagger 2.0, however I don't have this issue with my other projects.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In openapi 3.0.x they have replaced the parameters by requestBody as shown here https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/ So your file channels.js should look like this:

```
    class Channel extends BaseRouter {
/**
* @swagger
*
* definitions:
*   channel:
*     type: object
*     tags:
*       - Channels
*     properties:
*       name:
*           type: string
*       global:
*           type: boolean
*     required:
*       - name
*/

constructor(app, version) {
    super(app, new ChannelCtrl(), version);
}

post() {
    /**
     * @swagger
     * /api/v1/channels:
     *  post:
     *      tags:
     *          - Channels
     *      name: Create
     *      produces:
     *          - application/json
     *      consumes:
     *          - application/json
     *      summary: Create new channel object
     *      requestBody:
     *         content:
     *            application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
     *               schema:
     *                  type: object
     *                  properties:
     *                     field1:          # <!--- form field name
     *                        type: string
     *                     field2:          # <!--- form field name
     *                        type: string
     *      responses:
     *          '200':
     *              description: Channel object has been created
     *              application/json:
     *                  schema:
     *                      $ref: '#/definitions/channel'
     */
    this.app.post(`/api/${this.version}/channels`, this.controller.create.bind(this.controller));
    return this;
}
```